# LINQPad treating query as an update but Visual Studios is treating it as an Insert. What could be going wrong?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-6, linqpad

I have Entity Framework connected to an Oracle Database.

I have the following C# Code.

```
 using (var db = new myDB())
 {
     var temp = (from s in db.TABLE
     where s.ID == 5736
     select s).SingleOrDefault();
     temp.DONE = "A";
     db.Entry(temp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I am getting an item out of the database and then saving it back.

When I do this in VS an exception is thrown. The inner error gives me an ORACLE error.

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYDB.SOME_THING_ID) violated

This to me indicates that I am trying to insert the changed item back into the database with the same ID of something that is in there.

When the same code is run through LINQPad as a C# Statement. No error is thrown. When Examining the SQL executed it does indeed do an update.

Checking the database my item has been updated.

The same .DLL for data access and the same .comfig files are being used. I am perplexed to what could be going wrong.

Comment: See what SQL EF is generating and try running it in SQL Developer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: the statement reads like an Update.  So, when you say VS is doing the work, do you mean IIS, IISExpress, or some other application?  I ask, because VS doesn't usually execute code.